# Sending message to web-service error

Tags: java, spring, web-services

When I send a request on the web-service via SoapUI request passes and returns the correct answer. If the program sends the request (java + spring), it throws out an error:

```
    org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:561) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at ru.fms.sx.adapter.base.sws.SpringWSClientFactory$GenericSWSClient.invokeService(SpringWSClientFactory.java:224) ~[adapters-api-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at ru.fms.sx.adapter.base.sws.SpringWSClientFactory$GenericSWSClient.invoke(SpringWSClientFactory.java:163) ~[adapters-api-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at $Proxy329.request(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at ru.fms.sx.adapter.cregistry.impl.CRegistryRawXmlAdapter.submitImportOrgStructureRequest(CRegistryRawXmlAdapter.java:88) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at ru.fms.sx.adapter.container.dto.ExtendedAdapterDto.invokeMethod(ExtendedAdapterDto.java:66) [adapters-container-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at ru.fms.sx.kernel.task.impl.TaskProcessor.invokeAdapterMethod(TaskProcessor.java:796) [sx-kernel-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at ru.fms.sx.kernel.task.impl.TaskProcessor.processOutgoingTask(TaskProcessor.java:420) [sx-kernel-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at ru.fms.sx.kernel.task.impl.DelayedOutgoingTaskExecutor.run(DelayedOutgoingTaskExecutor.java:137) [sx-kernel-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_05]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_05]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_05]

    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_05]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:123) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:157) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity.writeTo(ByteArrayEntity.java:112) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:155) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:149) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:236) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:121) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsConnection.onSendAfterWrite(HttpComponentsConnection.java:120) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:48) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:654) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:603) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
... 17 common frames omitted
```

Web-service configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
<bean id="crRawXmlServiceMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="ru.fms.sx.adapter.cregistry.rawxml.wsclient" />
</bean>

<bean id="crRawXmlServiceClient" class="ru.fms.sx.adapter.base.sws.SpringWSClientFactory"
      factory-method="createClient">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Class"
                     value="ru.fms.sx.adapter.cregistry.rawxml.wsclient.RegistryUpdatePort" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="crRawXmlServiceTemplate" />
</bean>

<bean id="crRawXmlServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="crRawXmlServiceMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="crRawXmlServiceMarshaller" />
    <property name="messageSender">
        <bean class="ru.fms.sx.adapter.base.sws.SXMessageSender">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="${http.proxy.host}" />
            <constructor-arg index="1" value="${http.proxy.port}" />
            <property name="channel" value="SMEV" />
            <property name="readTimeout" value="24000000" />
            <property name="connectionTimeout" value="24000000"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="destinationProvider" ref="destinationProvider" />
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="wsSecHandler" />
            <ref bean="soapSigner" />
            <ref bean="soapLogger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="destinationProvider" class="ru.fms.sx.adapter.base.OutgoingServiceDestinationProvider">
    <property name="defaultUri" value="${cregistry.rawxml.ws.url}" />
</bean>
```

Does anyone know what it could be?

Comment: Are you running both tests from the same machine? Is your ${cregistry.rawxml.ws.url} identical to the URL you use in SoapUI?

Comment: Yes, at the same. And URL is correct

Comment: Is there any SSL involved?

Comment: Yes. The connection runs over SSL

Comment: Is that just an https connection, or client certificate auth?